# How to call the constructor of reference members in the member initializer list?

Tags: c++

Consider this example:

```
class C {};

class B {
public:
  B(C& c) : c_(c) {};
private:
  C& c_;
};

class A {
public:
  A(C& c) : b(c) {};
private:
  B& b;
};
```

`A` has a reference member `b` of class `B`. `B` has a constructor that takes a reference of class `C`. `A`'s constructor takes a reference of class `C` and tries to initialize `b` by calling the latter's constructor with `c`.

But clang complains with the following message:

```
wtf.cpp:12:13: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'B' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'C'
  A(C& c) : b(c) {};
            ^ ~
1 error generated.
```

It sounds almost as if clang thought I was assigning `c` to `b`, but my intent is to call `B`'s constructor with `c`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't do what you want to do, not without an actual instance of `B` for `A::b` to reference. Does `A::b` *have* to be a reference? Why?

Comment: `A` has a reference to a `B`. Where is the `B` you are trying to bind that reference to? What is its lifetime?

Comment: You could do something like that, https://ideone.com/eW2nwZ, very unsafe.

Comment: Given you said you wanna call the ctor of `B` in initializer of `A`, what you actually in mind for `A::b` is `B` instead of `B&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is not restricted to initializer lists, but to the usual construction of references. The following should not compile:

```
class C
{};

class B
{
public:
    B(C& c)
    : c_(c)
    {}
private:
    C& c_;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    B b0(c);  // This works because you actually create an object of type B.

    B& b1(c);  // Error, cannot construct reference to B from C.
    B& b2 = c;  // Same as above, only a different notation.
    // You cannot write a constructor of B to make these lines work,
    // because you do not create an object of type B.
}
```

An object of class `B` can be constructed from a reference to a `C` object, but the same does not hold for references. A reference can only be created from an object of the same type, or a type below in inheritance hierarchy.

That is exactly the point of a reference: You do not construct an object. You just introduce a new name for an object that was created somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. A reference is in fact close to non modifiable pointer. That means that a `B&` can only reference a object of class `B` or of a sub-class of `B`. And there is nothing like the construction of a reference.

You could construct a temporary `B` object from the `C` reference, but you cannot initialize a reference with a temporary object, because as soon as the reference will have be initialized, the referenced object would be destroyed.

So you must store a real object an not a ref in A:

```
    class A {
    public:
      A(C& c) : b(c) {};
    private:
      B b;
    };
```